# Filter entries by tags

Tags: navigation, tags, sorting

Still very new to Craft but just can't figure this problem out, it's a level above me at the moment.

I have an FAQ page as a 'single' that I would like to display all entries from a channel by default.

But all these entries will have a tag option (either 'red' or 'blue').

How would I sort these entries via a sub nav to display only all, red or blue tagged entries?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about how to use [Relations](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html) in the docs. All relations such as (Tags) can be fetched via `relatedTo` parameter in your `ElementsQuery`

```PHP
{% set tagId = craft.app.getRequest().getQueryParam('tagId') %}
{% set entries = craft
    .entries
    .section('faq')
    .relatedTo(tagId)
    .all() 
%}
```

This assumes you include the parameter `tagId` when someone clicks on your Tag, and that represents the ID of your Tag

```TWIG
{% for tag in craft.tags.group(1).all() %}
    <a href="?tagId={{ tag.id }}">{{ tag.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```